# how to have a modal popping up while Google streetview running in the background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, modal-dialog

I have been using the Google Maps API, specifically the streetview one. My goal is to have a modal that pops up while being in streetview mode. I will share the code that i am using for the modal, however they are in two separate folder in my project. Does anyone know how to have a modal popping up while having a running function in the background? (BTW i am using the Modal component from REACT)

I have tried go call the component "GoogleMApsStreetView" that contains the Google Maps API before calling the component "Modal"

```
<div>
        {<GoogleMapsStreetView />}
        <Modal
        className="Modal"
        className="content-Modal"
```

But what happens is that the modal shows up with streetview in the background but only for a millisecond, when it disappears only the streetview appears on the screen.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from 'react-modal';
import GoogleMapsStreetView from "./GoogleMapsStreetView.js";


export default class LevelOne extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      modalIsOpen: true
    };
  }
    /*this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);
    this.afterOpenModal = this.afterOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.closeModal = this.closeModal.bind(this);
  }

  openModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: true});
  }

  afterOpenModal() {
    // to change text color in modal
    //this.subtitle.style.color = '#000000';
  }

  closeModal() {
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: false});
  }*/

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        {<GoogleMapsStreetView />}
        <Modal
        className="Modal"
        className="content-Modal"

          isOpen={this.state.modalIsOpen}
          onAfterOpen={this.afterOpenModal}
          onRequestClose={this.closeModal}
          contentLabel="Example Modal"
        >


          <center><h2 style = {{color: '#444444'}}>Hello Jane!</h2></center>
          <center><button onClick={this.closeModal}>close</button></center>
        </Modal>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
```